# Checkbox always returns false value in Django form

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelForm with a checkbox, and I want to save the status of the checkbox into a model. But somehow, it just saves unchecked even if I have selected the checkbox. Here is my code:

forms.py:

```
    class UserLocation_updated(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['lat','lng','user_address','is_private']
```

checkbox field in models.py :

```
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and views.py :

```
    if request.method=="POST":
        print(request.POST)
        updatelocation_form = UserLocation_updated(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
        if updatelocation_form.is_valid():
            updatelocation_form.save()
            return redirect('userlocation_update')

    # enter code here
```

Comment: coud you show your template?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="is_private" name="is_private" value="{{user_info.is_private}}">

Comment: request.POST data please?

Comment: Did you hard-code the checkbox input in your template? If so, that is the problem. In your views, you should pass the form to the template, and you should use something like {{ form }} in your template

Comment: but i need to customize my form in template with css style

Comment: request.post :'is_private': ['False'] and when it is not checked it sends nothing in Post

Comment: To style form, you can use widgets and widget-tweaks. You have to pass form from view to template